# Get the value of a boundfield that is not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have in my gridview the following two BoundFields

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProductId" HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" Visible = "false" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDescription" HeaderText="product Description" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
```

How can I obtain the value of the first bound field if its set to visible false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the value of BoundField that is invisible. You have to use `TemplateField` and add the `HiddenField` control in it and bind its Value property.

Markup,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" 
                    Value='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>' />
                 ....
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind to get the value from HiddenField control of 1st cell of each row.

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
  {
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
       HiddenField productid = row.Cells[0].FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
       ...
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

With IDs it is better to use `DataKeyNames` property on the GridView

```
DataKeyNames="ProductId"
```

then in code behind you can get it

```
GridView1.DataKeys[row_index]["ProductId"]
```